# Base image can not be fetched within Dockerfile build but can be fetched from shell

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rproxy

Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:    24.0.6

OS: RHEL8

I want to build an existing docker compose project on a new VM. The docker compose project consists of two containers *db* and *web*.

I have to go through our corporate proxy.

*db* gets fetched and built without any problem. But then *web* fails. *web* is based on python bullseye. It can not fetch the bullseye image:

```
[+] Running 10/10
 ✔ db 9 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                                                                                                             7.5s
   ✔ 661ff4d9561e Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               1.1s
   ✔ c1d93bf5ce63 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               0.7s
   ✔ 9344ea92d0fd Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               0.7s
   ✔ be45118cb34b Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               3.4s
   ✔ 614e68220451 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               1.1s
   ✔ a907e8a572e0 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               1.5s
   ✔ cbbd25672b6d Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               1.6s
   ✔ a7057bfcf742 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               5.5s
   ✔ c6dde99972d3 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                               2.0s
DEBU[0007] using default config store "/root/.docker/buildx"
[+] Building 0.5s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                    docker:default
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 3.14kB                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.57kB                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.0rc2-bullseye                                                                                                                        0.4s
------
 > [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.0rc2-bullseye:
------
DEBU[0007] using default config store "/root/.docker/buildx"
DEBU[0007] serving grpc connection
DEBU[0007] stopping session                              span="load buildkit capabilities"
DEBU[0007] serving grpc connection
DEBU[0008] stopping session
failed to solve: python:3.11.0rc2-bullseye: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fpython%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp 3.219.239.5:443: connect: connection refused
```

However, if I pull bullseye via the shell it can fetch it without any problems.

Also, as soon as I have fetched bullseye the rest of the *web* container builds.

I have set the proxies via:

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
```

and

```
/root/.docker/config.json
```

Also, I think in general the proxy is set correctly, because:

1. *db* gets fetched from docker repo normally.
2. If I fetch bullseye from the command line, *web* builds without any problem, even though it also has to fetch stuff from outside our corp. net.

EDIT: I did not set proxy via shell envs, because we want to set proxy tool specific.